# How to redirect a URL with random search query using .htaccess?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I'm using the plugin "Relevanssi" on a client's WordPress site for better search and search highlighting. Works great, but has a problem when I click one particular link right after doing a search. The search query is pasted after that link and the requested page (i.e. `/contact/agenda/`) is garbled. That's why I want to redirect the URL to that page that has a search query starting with `?highlight=` (e.g. `/contact/agenda/?highlight=searchterm`) to standard a URL to that page.

I've tried about any example I could find. In particular, I had a look at https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/redirects/301-redirect-query-string and https://perishablepress.com/redirect-query-string-htaccess/. Copied, pasted and tried to no avail.

This is the .htaccess I have so far:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/contact/agenda/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} highlight=([a-z]+) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /contact/agenda/ [R=301,L,NE]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

The result I want is for any search query on `/contact/agenda` to redirect to `/contact/agenda`. For example: `/contact/agenda/?highlight=kip` should redirect to `/contact/agenda/`. Also, `/contact/agenda/?highlight=kippensoep` should redirect to `/contact/agenda/`, etc.
Instead, the current `htaccess` code does not redirect any search query with `/contact/agenda/?highlight=searchterm`. I have no error messages either.

Answer (score 0):

When Apache redirects, it keeps the query string. Use `QSD` to delete the query string.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/contact/agenda/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} highlight=([a-z]+) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /contact/agenda/ [R=301,L,NE,QSD]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Anonymous, but I'm afraid it didn't work. In the meantime, I have implemented a workaround: I now use a different, non-existent path in the link that is giving me the headache and redirect that to the correct path. It works, but it feels like using a band aid. My original problem wasn't solved. I'm also mailing the plugin (Relevanssi) author, because I think it may be a bug in the plugin that adds the search query to menu links in the first place.

Comment: @OmeCor Are you using `QSD` when you redirect from the other URL or does it not work for both URLs?